# How to use S3 static web hosting (conditional redirect) with Cloudfront OAI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I am using static website hosting on S3, specifically for the conditional redirect so I can redirect 404 responses to a lambda function:

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "404"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "<MY LAMBDA>",
            "HttpRedirectCode": "307",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyPrefixWith": "prod/"
        }
    }
]
```

This is working well when my bucket is public, but I want to make my bucket private and use Cloudfront OAI so it can only be accessed through Cloudfront.

The issue is, when I make the bucket private, the Cloudfront pointing to the S3 static website stops working and returns 403 responses.

Under the Cloudfront origin settings, I don't see a way to add OAI for the distribution. Is there any way to use OAI and still take advantage of the conditional redirects with S3 static website hosting? Also, if my lambda accesses the bucket, do I need to add an extra bucket policy to allow access for the lambda, even though the lambda already has API keys?

I've tried changing the cloudfront origin to point directly to the S3 bucket instead of the S3 static website, but then the redirects stop working.

(To give a little extra info, the S3 is storing media files, not a website. The lambda is a dynamic image resizing app, so if the S3 hits a 404 for a specific image size, the lambda will upload a new file with that size and then redirect back to the Cloudfront/S3 endpoint).

Comment: So you went through this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html and the OAI settings were not available?

Comment: Yes. I can see the OAI settings if the distribution points directly to the bucket, but not if it's pointing to the S3 Static Website. And if I point it directly to the bucket, the redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh I see you are just doing a redirect on 404 errors. Why not do that in CloudFront instead of trying to do it in S3? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GeneratingCustomErrorResponses.html

Comment: I had the same thought, but it seems like they want you to point to an S3 file like `error.html` rather than an endpoint. How would I send the request to a lambda with all the path params intact?

Comment: Yeah maintaining the path parameters is difficult here. I think you may have to use Lambda@Edge to intercept the 404 response from S3 and rewrite it into a redirect maybe. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html

Comment: Oh cool. Would that be a separate lambda that specifically handles the 404, or is it possible to add an extra config setting on the lambda I'm already using?

Comment: I believe that would need to be a separate Lambda, as it gets deployed differently.